# Viewing an archive of Facebook Posts

Tags: facebook, data-liberation

I want to be able to view the entire archive for a Facebook page. Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't allow pagination, so it is very difficult to view the archive for a page given how easy it is to lose my place and how much the page will slow down as my memory usage increases.

I want to be able to view the entire archive of a Facebook page, including the photos posted, with pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You could [download a copy of your information on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/).

[image: settings]
[image: download]

Memory usage could be less of an issue offline. This might be the best solution at the moment as I don't believe there are any updated plugins or extensions to automatically paginate your Facebook feed.